# IntelliJ doesn't detect the device

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have connected my Samsung Galaxy S4 to my mac using USB cable. I also enable USB Debugging mode on the phone but IntelliJ box says again  "no devices".
I can't run my project because of this. I'm using a 2019 MacBook Pro.
How can I solve? I tried to search for this question but not solved yet. Thanks all

Comment: Make sure you check on trust that device & computer

Comment: @peprumo how can i do that? No popup showing when i connect the device

Comment: Then make sure developer options and usb debugging are on. When they are on the popup will show up

Comment: Both developer options and USB debugging mode are on as I said in the post. Nothing happens.